# Flutter How to make listview below search bar?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, search

I want the listview to show below the search bar. It has a problem as in the example picture, it overlaps.
I use the search bar from pubdev.

This is a example image

[image]

This is a Code

```
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: CustomAppBar(),
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
  body: Stack(
    fit: StackFit.expand,
    children: [
      Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
              child: items.isNotEmpty != 0
                  ? ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: items.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Card(
                          child: Container(
                              child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              ListTile(
                                  title: Text(
                                    items[index].name!,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                        fontSize: 18.0,
                                        fontFamily: 'supermarket'),
                                  ),                                 
                            ],
                          )),
                        );
                      },
                    )
                  : Center(
                      child: Text('Search'),
                    )),
        ],
      ),
      buildFloatingSearchBar(),
    ],
  ),
);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you don't need Stack so just use Column

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: CustomAppBar(),
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          // search bar
          buildFloatingSearchBar(),
          Expanded(
            child: items.isNotEmpty != 0
                ? ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: items.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Card(
                        child: Container(
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              ListTile(
                                title: Text(
                                  items[index].name!,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                      fontSize: 18.0,
                                      fontFamily: 'supermarket'),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  )
                : Center(
                    child: Text('Search'),
                  ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're in a `Stack` widget, to make the `ListView` show *below* the SearchBar, you should first arrange the searchBar and then arrange the ListView. So, simply reverse the order of the `ListView()` and `SearchBar`:

```dart
Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: [
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              // --> Call the SearchBar widget here
              Flexible(child: buildFloatingSearchBar()),
              Expanded(
                  child: items.isNotEmpty != 0
                      ? ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: items.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Card(
                                child: Container(
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  ListTile(title: items[index]),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ));
                          },
                        )
                      : Center(
                          child: Text('Search'),
                        )),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

This is if you insist on using a `Stack`. You might want to consider using a `Column()` widget instead.

Answer (score 2):

use Column instead of Stack inside Body Widget

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('AppBar')),
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 80,
            width: 100.w,
            color: Colors.green,
            child: Text('Replace With Your Searchbar '),
          ),
          Expanded(
              child: items.isNotEmpty != 0
                  ? ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: items.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Card(
                          child: Container(
                              child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              ListTile(
                                title: Text(
                                  items[index].toString(),
                                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, fontSize: 18.0, fontFamily: 'supermarket'),
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          )),
                        );
                      },
                    )
                  : Center(
                      child: Text('Search'),
                    )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```